# Consider $\frac{abc-defc+fagh-iafg}{6}=337$ ($abc$ means $100a+10b+c.$ Find the maximum value of $iafg.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, decimal-expansion

$\frac{abc-defc+fagh-iafg}{6}=337$

The string of letters are numbers so when the equation had $fagh$ it represents $1000f+100a+10g+h.$ Try to find the maximum of $iafg.$ Good luck!

Comment: The division by 6 seems unnecessary. Wouldn't it be simpler to omit it and write "$\ldots = 2022$”?

Comment: Are different letters representing different numbers?

Comment: @JetfiRex the number abc would mean $100a+10b+c$ where $b,c$ are from $0-9$ and $a$ is from $1-9.$ So if $a=1,b=2,c=3,$ then the number would be $123$

Comment: You're not answering my question... I mean, could we have two different letters representing the same number, or all the letters representing distinct numbers? For example, could $a=b$ so $abc=aac$?

Comment: Sorry, yes, if a=1, then a remains 1 throughout the whole expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this because it doesn't take too long and I think the technique is worth seeing. This and similar problems can be slaughtered with [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), which is implemented in [sage](https://sagemath.org), for instance.

Given *linear* constraints, we can efficiently maximize a linear target function. If we add bonus constraints that some variables should only be allowed integer values, then the worst case difficulty skyrockets, but many problems (particularly those as small as this) can still be quickly solved in practice.

As an example, here's the sage code for this particular problem, which I think is self explanatory. It solves the problem in roughly $4$ milliseconds.

```
p = MixedIntegerLinearProgram()
v = p.new_variable(integer=True, nonnegative=True)
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = v['a'], v['b'], v['c'], v['d'], v['e'], v['f'], v['g'], v['h'], v['i']

p.add_constraint(a <= 9)
p.add_constraint(b <= 9)
p.add_constraint(c <= 9)
p.add_constraint(d <= 9)
p.add_constraint(e <= 9)
p.add_constraint(f <= 9)
p.add_constraint(g <= 9)
p.add_constraint(h <= 9)
p.add_constraint(i <= 9)

p.add_constraint((100*a+10*b+c) - (1000*d+100*e+10*f+c) + (1000*f+100*a+10*g+h) - (1000*i+100*a+10*f+g) == 337*6)

# this is the value we're maximizing
p.set_objective(1000*i + 100*a + 10*f + g)

# this computes the maximum
p.solve()
```

Since you've listed this as a problem for us to solve, rather than something you want help with, I'll leave the output of `p.solve()` under a fold.

> 7999
>
>  $$\frac{920 - 0890 + 9991 - 7999}{6} = 337$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: dang...big brain, but when $defc=0890,$ it is no longer a $4$ digit integer, so your code could be revised a little bit. Overall though, this solution is really impressive. I have a question though, what is the algorithm the computer uses to do it so quickly?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually. Almost certainly it's some flavor of [branch and bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). I think sage's default integer/linear programming solver is [GLPK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Linear_Programming_Kit) so if you're interested in the exact algorithm you can find more by checking out their documentation.

Comment: cool! very cool!